# Force on a magnetic dipole in an external magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I want to find an expression for the force acting upon a magnetic dipole with dipole moment $\mathbf{m}$ if that dipole is positioned in a stationary, external magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$. The expression given for the force is the following (assuming that $\nabla \times\mathbf{B}=0$):

$$\mathbf{F}=(\mathbf{m}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}\quad(1)$$

My question is mostly whether the expression above is equivalent to:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial y}& \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{m} \quad (2)$$

or equivalent to:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial y}& \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}^T\mathbf{m} \quad (3)$$

I basically found these two expressions ($(2)$ $(3)$) for the force from two different sources, so one of them must be wrong. I derived the first expression in the following way:

$$(\mathbf{m}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}=(m_1\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+m_2\frac{\partial }{\partial y}+m_3\frac{\partial }{\partial z})\begin{bmatrix}
B_1\\ 
B_2\\ 
B_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
m_1\frac{\partial B_1}{\partial x}
+ m_2\frac{\partial B_1}{\partial y}
+ m_3\frac{\partial B_1}{\partial z}
\\ 
m_1\frac{\partial B_2}{\partial x}
+ m_2\frac{\partial B_2}{\partial y}
+ m_3\frac{\partial B_2}{\partial z}
\\ 
m_1\frac{\partial B_3}{\partial x}
+ m_2\frac{\partial B_3}{\partial y}
+ m_3\frac{\partial B_3}{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}$$

The last expressions can be interpreted as the Matrix product $(2)$. Is that correct or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, use coordinates and index notation; the expression

$$\mathbf{F}=(\mathbf{m}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}~~~(*)
$$

can be written in cartesian coordinates in this way:

$$
F_i = m_k \partial_k B_i
$$

If you're wondering how do we know that the right-hand side of (*) expands this way, it is actually the definition of the shorthand $\mathbf m \cdot \nabla$.

If force coordinates are put into a row $\mathbf F^T$, then this row can be obtained as left multiplication of the matrix $\mathbf G$ with coordinates $G_{ki} = \partial_k B_i$ by the magnetic moment row $\mathbf m^T$:

$$
\mathbf F^T = \mathbf m^T \cdot \mathbf G.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response but I think your result might have an incorrect dimension since $\mathbf{m}^T\mathbf{G} \in \mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ and $\mathbf{F}\in\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$.

Comment: @Mantabit you are right, the force on the left-hand side also has to be written as a row, because $i$ is a column index. It is fixed now.

Comment: Okay thanks, I checked your solution and it agrees with mine.